# Inserting text if .next does not match another element immediately after current element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to look for the span element _fieldName and if it is followed by a .mandatory span element then do nothing. But if _fieldName is not followed by .mandatory span element then I want to add a text string immediately after the ._fieldName element. Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <span class="_fieldName">Name</span>
   <span class="mandatory">*</span>
   <span class="_fieldName">Email address</span>
</div>
```

This code works:

```
<script>

if($("span._fieldName").next("span.mandatory").length > 0)

{
$("span._fieldName")
}
else {
$( "<p>(Optional)</p>" ).insertAfter( "span._fieldName" );
}

</script>
```

But it adds (Optional) after every span._fieldName. I only want to add it after the Email address field because it does not have span.mandatory immediately after it. Is this possible?

Comment: I am wondering why you are using spans. Are you using these as labels for inputs? Can you alter the HTML any? You could easily have CSS add the * and optional text without the HTML elements in the markup.

Comment: Hi, the HTML is not editable - this is how our forms platform renders labels. It was not possible to do this just with CSS as otherwise it would add optional onto a mandatory field as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: *not* `!`, [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/)

```js
$('._fieldName').each(function() {
  if( !$(this).next().is('.mandatory') ) {
    $(this).after('<p>(Optional)</p>');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="_fieldName">Name</span>
  <span class="mandatory">*</span>
  <span class="_fieldName">Email address</span>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you're dealing with all `span._fieldName` elements at once. You need to loop through them and individually check them to see what their next element is. To do that you can use `each()`, like this:

```js
$('span._fieldName').each(function() {
  if ($(this).next('span.mandatory').length == 0) {
    $("<p>(Optional)</p>").insertAfter(this);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="_fieldName">Name</span>
  <span class="mandatory">*</span>
  <span class="_fieldName">Email address</span>
</div>
```